# Access object from outside of function

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2

In a plotting function, I am referring to an object that has been generated by a higher level function, i.e. my plotting function is nested within a higher level function.

The code sort of looks like this:

```
minaverage <- seq(1:1440)

plot_minaverage <- function(minaverage){
  for_minaverage_plot.time <- rep(seq(1,1440),2)
  seq <- seq(start.time*60, length.out = 1440)
  minaverage_plot_time <- for_minaverage_plot.time[seq]

  minaverage_plot_df <- data.frame (minaverage_plot_time, minaverage)

  pp <- ggplot(minaverage_plot_df, aes(x=minaverage_plot_time, y = minaverage))+ 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
theme_bw()
print(pp)
}
```

The problem I have is that minverage is computed outside of the function and when I do not store it in workspace using `minaverage <<- minaverage`, the plotting function cannot access it.

How can I access minaverage?

Comment: Since a [“higher order function”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) is something different, I’ve edited the question to not use that term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `minaverage` via a parameter, this isn’t a problem.

Your code almost works, you just need to add `start.time` as a parameter, and you have a typo in your second to last line:

```
theme_bw()+
```

Remove the `+` to make it work:

```
plot_minaverage = function(minaverage, start.time){
    for_minaverage_plot.time <- rep(seq(1,1440),2)
    seq <- seq(start.time*60, length.out = 1440)
    minaverage_plot_time <- for_minaverage_plot.time[seq]

    minaverage_plot_df <- data.frame (minaverage_plot_time, minaverage)

    pp <- ggplot(minaverage_plot_df, aes(x=minaverage_plot_time, y = minaverage))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
        theme_bw()
    print(pp)
}
```

Comment: @ChristineBlume Yes you can, it’s right there. The code in my answer works for me.